# What is the best way to expose Cassandra REST API to web?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I would like to work with Cassandra from javascript web app using REST API.
REST should support basic commands working with DB - create table, select/add/update/remove items. Will be perfect to have something similar to odata protocol.

P.S. I'm looking for some library or component. Java is a most preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Staash solution looks perfect for the task - https://github.com/Netflix/staash

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataStax drivers. I used it via Scala but you can use Java, a Session object is a long-lived object and it should not be used in a request/response short-lived fashion but it's up to you.

ref. [rules when using datastax drivers](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/4-simple-rules-when-using-the-datastax-drivers-for-cassandra)

Answer (score -2):

There is no "best" language for REST APIs, it depends on what you're comfortable using. Virtually all languages will be able to do this reasonable well, depending on your skill level.

The obvious choice is probably java, because cassandra's written in java, the java driver from Datastax is well supported, and because it's probably pretty easy to find some spring REST frameworks to do what you want. Second beyond that would be python - again, good driver support and REST frameworks with things like django or flask+potion. Ruby driver isn't bad, lots of ruby REST APIs out there, too.

Comment: Thank you Jeff for the comment. But I'm interesting not in language. I'm looking for framework or library so that I would prefer reuse already written component instead of inventing own wheel. Yes, java is a most preferred platform.

Comment: You likely won't find any component that's of much use, other than perhaps the datastax driver ( https://github.com/datastax/java-driver ), unless you wanted to build it around the OpsCenter product datastax provides.